# How to integrate a word processing tool into my website

Tags: web-applications, google-api, integration, google-drive-realtime-api

I want to know if it's possible to integrate a word processing tool (i.e. Google docs) into my website. So a user can login, open his/her document, and collaborate/work with my team on a document throughout my website interface. Is it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot any longer use the **Google Docs API** to integrate a word processor into your website. Read it [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/)...
>
> Instead you will have to use the **[Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/)** along with **[ZOHO](https://www.zoho.com/gadgets/blog/zoho-office-integrates-google-drive.html)**. Try **[ZOHO Docs](https://www.zoho.com/docs/)**...
>
> For more doubts or questions related to Google Drive API you can post questions here in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-sdk).

Let me also present you with some alternatives here:

**Word Processors:**

- [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/support/word_processor_integration)

**Text Editors:**

- [YUI](http://yui.github.io/yui2/)
- [Tiny MCE](http://www.freerichtexteditor.com/)
- [Fre Rich Text Editor](http://www.freerichtexteditor.com/)

I hope this helps or gives some direction to your application development...